# Squid service starts and stops forever

Tags: proxy, squid, ubuntu-16.04

so i have a server with Ubuntu 16.04. There runs a Squid ( Squid Cache: Version 3.5.12 ). It should function as forward proxy, authenticating the user then leading him/her forward to a peer.

But Squid just starts then stops after like 20sec and then starts again.

```
Feb 20 10:11:41 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23215 exited due to signal 6 with status 0
Feb 20 10:11:44 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23321 started
Feb 20 10:12:09 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23321 exited due to signal 6 with status 0
Feb 20 10:12:12 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23429 started
Feb 20 10:12:37 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23429 exited due to signal 6 with status 0
Feb 20 10:12:40 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23535 started
Feb 20 10:13:05 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23535 exited due to signal 6 with status 0
Feb 20 10:13:08 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23608 started
Feb 20 10:13:33 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23608 exited due to signal 6 with status 0
Feb 20 10:13:36 proxy squid[12566]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 23722 started
```

I have no idea why. I red in other forums that you have to delete the cache and rebuild it but that did not help.

squid.conf passes the squid -k reconfigure so iam pretty sure its not in the config.

I hope somebody could help me to fix that.

thanks for you time.

EDIT: Not sure if it helps. In the short period the squid is active, it works fine. So I can connect and authenticate and get to the internet.

EDIT 2 : 
Last lines from cache.log

```
2017/02/20 11:29:27.751 kid1| ctx: exit level  0
2017/02/20 11:29:27.751 kid1| 20,2| store.cc(954) checkCachable: StoreEntry::checkCachable: NO: not cachable
2017/02/20 11:29:27.751 kid1| 20,2| store.cc(954) checkCachable: StoreEntry::checkCachable: NO: not cachable
2017/02/20 11:29:27.751 kid1| 20,2| store.cc(954) checkCachable: StoreEntry::checkCachable: NO: not cachable
2017/02/20 11:29:27.751 kid1| assertion failed: stmem.cc:228: "target.range().end > target.range().start"
```

Edit 3:  Update.
Thanks to you and a lot of trying i could pin the problem down. Squid only starting and stopping and so on if i put in the second cache_peer. Without that it works fine.

Comment: what's the output of `ulimit -n`?

Comment: Any error message in `/var/log/squid/cache.log`?

Comment: `ulimit -n` gives me 1024 as root. I cant log in as the proxy user. getting _This account is currently not available._
`/var/log/squid/cache.log` no errors or warnings. just seeing Pinger exiting.

Comment: @BitKoch, please post your cache.log too.

Comment: @bangal how much you need? its a pretty huge log. I will put something in the original post.

Comment: @BitKoch, may be you can post a few more lines. You can also use http://pastebin.com/ if you want. I guess cache.log is your best source to find possible error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Solved***:
So as i wrote that one cache_peer was troublesome and if active, squid would restart over and over again. I saw in the logs that it wanted a netdb from that cache_peer. So i added `no-netdb-exchange` to the options from the cache_peer in the `etc/squid/squid.conf`.  Now it serves as wanted and doesn’t restart over and over any more.
Thank you all for helping and your time.

Comment: The question field is for questions and the answer field is for answers.